# Parsing out image URLS and other URLS separately

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing

I have a javascript function that will take a chunk of user input, and replace all image URLS with an HTML image, and all other URLS with HTML links. The only problem is, my solution is ugly! :P

Here is my current strategy:

Use regex to first replace all Image URLS in the text with a place marker, like "#IMG[1]IMG#", and then the URL for the Image is stored in an array so it can be replaced later.

Then, the normal URLs are replaced by a regex replace. Afterwards, the image placeholders are replaced with the appropriate image tags.

This works, but it is really messy. It would be great to just do 2 regex string replacements, but then the Image URL's would get busted when the normal URL's are replaced with links.

Any ideas for a strategy that solves this issue more elegantly would be very much appreciated. Of course, if I could get a regex that finds all URLs without getting image URLs, that would also solve my problem. Here is my current regex for finding a URL:

```
/((https?:\/\/[^\s'"]+)|([^\s'"]*www[^\s'"]+\.[^\s'"]{2,})|([^\s'"]+\.(com|net|org|jp|gov)[^\s'"]*))/g
```

Comment: Is the text HTML or is it just plain text image urls?

Comment: The original text is just plain text - shouldn't contain any HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do something like this:

```
((https?:\/\/[^\s'"]+)|([^\s'"]*www[^\s'"]+\.[^\s'"]{2,})|([^\s'"]+\.(com|net|org|jp|gov)[^\s'"]*))(?<!jpg)(?<!png)(?=\s|$|'|")
```

And add other image extensions for each one you want to skip when looking for URLs that aren't images.